# JavaScript runtime error: 'Microsoft' is undefined

Tags: javascript, windows-store-apps, winjs

I am trying to develop the first Windows Store app using Javascript.
Here is the link to the documentation page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh852186.aspx

Calling-

```
Microsoft.Maps.loadModule('Microsoft.Maps.Map', { callback: initMap, culture: "en-us", homeRegion: "US" });
```

in the default.js file leads to the following error:

> 0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'Microsoft' is undefined The
>   program '[4864] WWAHost.exe' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).

Whereas I did include the following in the default.html file

```
<!-- BingMaps JavaScript Control references -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="ms-appx:///Bing.Maps.JavaScript//js/veapicore.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="ms-appx:///Bing.Maps.JavaScript//js/veapiModules.js"></script>
```

Comment: Just check it twice that you have followed all the steps mentioned on MSDN like downloading and installing 'Bing Maps SDK for Windows Store apps (for Windows 8.1)'. Because error clearly says that JavaScipt is not getting any thing related to Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you've added "Bing Maps for JavaScript" in your project references. This is step 3 in the documentation you note:

> In Solution Explorer, right-click References for your project and select Add Reference. Expand Windows and then select Extensions.
>   Select Bing Maps for JavaScript, and then click OK to add the
>   reference. The default installation path for the Bing Maps SDK for
>   Windows Store apps is C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Microsoft
>   SDKs\Windows\v8.0\ExtensionSDKs\Bing.Maps.JavaScript

I can repro your issue in my own app if I remove the reference. In short, the reference is what makes sure that Bing Maps is deployed with your app so that your script tags actually resolve. Without the reference in your project, those files won't be loaded and the "Microsoft" namespace won't exist.